# Why is PerformanceCounter divided by ProcessorCount not 1?

Tags: c#, .net, process, performancecounter

I am currently doing a ProcessorCounter with a ProgressBar control to check how much CPU power a certain process is hogging, much like how the TaskManager would do it.
The thing is. I tried doing this.

```
PerformanceCounter pCounterServerUsageCpu = new PerformanceCounter("Process", "% Processor Time", process.ProcessName);
```

And then doing this to actually append the value to the ProgressBar

```
pgCpuPerformance.Value = (float)pCounterServerUsageCpu.NextValue() / Environment.ProcessorCount;
```

That works very well, but I am not understanding WHY I need this part

```
/ Environment.ProcessorCount;
```

From what I have read on MSDN *Environment.ProcessorCount* only grabs the amount of CPU's you have on your PC. I have 1 CPU so it should devide it by 1 which should give the same output as this would

```
pgCpuPerformance.Value = (float)pCounterServerUsageCpu.NextValue();
```

It seems like the code above that doesnt divide by 1 provides a much higher value to the ProgressBar

And to be a little bit more clear what I am trying to pull is this
[image]

Why are the two giving two different outputs when (float)pCounterServerUsageCpu.NextValue() / 1 should give the same output?

Comment: Environment.ProcessorCount will return the number of logical cpu's on your machine.  1 CPU can contain more than 1 processor (called 'cores').  It is likely the value returned by environment.processorCount is greater than 1 in your case.

Comment: Ahh so it devides the NextValue() by 8! That makes more sense now!